# Cannot getSelectedItem() from Text Spinner

Tags: java, android, string, spinner, android-spinner

I'm calling my Spinner with the following String[] array:

```
    String[] quantity = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"};
    SetupQuantitySpinner(quantity);
```

This is my spinner, which holds the String[] array above:

```
public void SetupQuantitySpinner(String[] quantity) {
    Spinner spnr;
    spnr = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_quantity);
    String productQuantity = spnr.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println(productQuantity);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.custom_spinner,
            R.id.text_main_seen,
            quantity);
    spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Why can't I get the selected value from the Spinner? It's causing my VM to crash with no other explanation. The Spinner works, because if I remove the line getSelectedItem() everything works fine.

Comment: you are calling the  getSelectedItem() before setting the adapter tot spinner thatswhy you are getting nullpointereception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you call `getSelectedItem`,you havn't set adapter for spinner already.So you should call this after `setAdapter`.Like this:

```
public void SetupQuantitySpinner(String[] quantity) {
Spinner spnr;
spnr = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_quantity);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(),
        R.layout.custom_spinner,
        R.id.text_main_seen,
        quantity);
spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
spnr.setSelection(0);
String productQuantity = quantity[spnr.getSelectedItemPosition()];
System.out.println(productQuantity);
}
```

Comment: Why does it keep printing out "com.parse.ParseObject@5004fc6"? Do I have to do something like this? System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(productQuantity));

Comment: When call `getSelectedItem`,it returns current selected item,If you want to get your array string,call `getSelectedItemPosition()`,my answer has updated.